# Run mocha tests in parallel on azure docker pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, parallel-processing, mocha.js

Why when I run mocha tests in parallel via azure pipeline they always get executed one by one?

I have tried both with and without docker in the pipeline but no luck.
Also I've tried with locally built and pushed image and then run that image from Azure pipeline...still no luck. I get same unexpected results via GitHub actions as well.
However, local run with same configuration it works (even using Docker Desktop it works).

p.s. I do not want to use the solution of multiple agents.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently most cloud providers (I have checked for AWS, Azure and GitHub) they offer default VMs/agents with 2 CPU cores unless you pay for more of course.
This affects the mocha parallelization because
"By default, Mocha's maximum job count is n - 1, where n is the number of CPU cores on the machine."

Reference,
https://mochajs.org/#-parallel-p